JavaScript function redeclaration and hoisting
in this example in the MDN functions article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Functions
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="./script/first.js"></script>
    <script src="./script/second.js"></script>
    <script>
        greeting();
    </script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>

// first.js
const name = "Chris";
function greeting() {
  alert(`Hello ${name}: welcome to our company.`);
}

// second.js
const name = "Zaptec";
function greeting() {
  alert(`Our company is called ${name}.`);
}

why does the first greeting function execute but if i change the const name to just name
// second.js
name = "Zaptec";
function greeting() {
  alert(`Our company is called ${name}.`);
}

the second greeting method is executed?
my current understanding is that in the second case the greeting function in second.js is hoisted to the top so it overrides the first greeting method before the exception is thrown and the script is stopped but why doesn't this happen in the first case?

Because the second script doesn't load due to redeclaring a const..  Nothing to do with hoisting.

@Keith: Actually, I think there is still hoisting at play here, because otherwise it should have the same effect even without const, as reassigning name would still fail since name is a const. With hoisting though, the second greeting definition is executed first (successfully), followed by the failing reassignment. In case of both lines having const, this doesn't happen, as the error is then a SyntaxError and not a TypeError which happens at the parsing stage and not at the execution stage.

@CherryDT  It's what's happening that's nothing to do with hoisting, place everything in 1 single script tag, things make more sense.  I think what's confusing the OP is just the way Scripts are loaded..

@Keith I think the point is, why does the first case (both lines with const) result in Hello Chris: welcome to our company while the second case (first line with const  but second without) results in Our company is called Chris. And the answer is that in the first case, the second file's code doesn't run at all (due to syntax error) while in the second case, it is parsed and then starts executing, first executing the hoisted function definition (even though it's physically below the assignment), then the assignment, which now fails with a runtime error.

@CherryDT  Notice how the OP says this in reply to your questions -> the two cases both throw an exception so they should both stop the script but one of them doesn't.  IOW:  Doing 2 Script tags one after the other, does not work in the same way as 1 single script tag with all the code in.  As one script it doesn't matter what Error is thrown the script will fail and stop as the OP expected.

@Keith But that's exactly the point. Why does the second exception not prevent the second greeting definition from overriding the first? Because of hoisting. And that doesn't happen with the first exception because syntax errors occur during the parsing stage, before hoisting occurs. (Try it: change function greeting () to greeting = function () in the second script so it's no longer a function definition but an assignment of a function expression and hence no longer hoisted, and it will suddenly behave like in the first case again.)

@CherryDT  Yeah, I get that part.  The bit I was referring too is why the OP expected in both case the Scripts to fail in total,  your giving the reason why the second parses, and I agree with that.  My point was not that hoisting didn't happen, but why the behaviour in both cases doesn't stop everything..  Hope that makes sense..  I think were both maybe answering different parts of the question... :)

@CherryDT I didn't know that syntax errors are treated this way in JS, I thought that they act like any other exception, so they halt the execution only when they are executed. I'm new to JS (started learning it a week ago) could you guys recommend me a good free or paid source like a book to learn it in a deep way

@mahmoudmirghani It's logical if you consider what the alternative would be. What if the syntax error is from a stray { located before the function definition?

I thought that JS would try to figure out things like it always does even if there is a syntax error. but yeah that's my bad for not noticing that.
either way thanks.

Because the first error is a SyntaxError which happens before hoisting, while the second error is a TypeError which happens after hoisting.

The first case results in a SyntaxError: Identifier 'name' has already been declared caused by the second const name = ... line.
If you removed both const keywords, it "works" but actually changes the global window.name variable.
However, if you only remove the second const keyword, you get a different error: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable., and indeed it does use the second greeting definition, but with the first name!
You may wonder, why does the second case behave differently? It's because the SyntaxError happens while the file is parsed (only read, not executed yet). It fails at the first line and stops processing the rest of the file. On the other hand, the TypeError happens at runtime, during execution. At this point, the hoisting already took place! The second greeting was already moved up and the new function definition was already executed, overriding the previous one. Only afterwards, the const name = ... got executed and failed.

Recap:
First case (const in both files): Second file fails to parse with a SyntaxError. Nothing executes in that file.
Second case (const only in first file): Second file succeeds to be parsed, greeting is hoisted. Execution starts, the hoisted greeting definition is applied, then the const name = ... fails to execute with a TypeError and further execution stops (but there is nothing to execute there anymore anyway).

the two cases both throw an exception so they should both stop the script but one of them doesn't (the second case)

@mahmoudmirghani  A failed script loading doesn't stop the following or previous scripts from loading..  Note:  what your observing is not Javascript, but just the way scripts are loaded, if everything was in 1 script, then the redeclaring the const would have stopped everything.
